# Embedding JSON in responseText

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using jquery iframetransport (for blob uploading) and am forced to access my responses via data.responseText. I am able to embed simple JSON from my PHP such as

```
echo json_encode(array("response"=>"hello"));
```

And my console log will return

```
{"response" : "hello"}
```

But I need divs and to concat data from my PHP requests. I fail right away if I try to embed this:

```
echo json_encode(array("response"=>"<div>hello</div>"));
```

I end up with

```
{"response":"hello<\/div>"}
```

What can I do to have this kind of json data in a resposneText?

Comment: Why does the key suddenly change from response to rowData. Do you insert it into a DB before? If yes are you striping tags first?

Comment: This might help you - http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/

Comment: escaping is normal and isn't a problem when it gets parsed in browser. Losing the open tag makes no sense though

Comment: Is your structure always will be <div>hello</div> ?

Comment: Yes it will and also contain blobs, but that is another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you could cast `htmlentities()` to the response array. Like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('response' => htmlentities('<div>hello</div>')));
// {"response":"<div>hello<\/div>"}
exit;
```

On retrieving responses, since you're expecting JSON, add the `dataType:` property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blahblah.php',
    dataType: 'JSON', // this one
});
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you. While I now get what looks like perfect JSON code and everything's intact, I cannot seem to $.parseJSON(data.responseText). I get " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a "  :(

Comment: @user3822370 check out my revision this may help you

Comment: I had that. The issue seemed to be my quotes. I had to use htmlentites("<div class = 'test'>hello<div>")   but thank you!

Comment: @user3822370 you don't need to parse the JSON manually when your AJAX is configured to expect JSON in its return. The headers are not necessary when you do this in your AJAX call, but if you set the headers the AJAX call should detect automatically that it's JSON and parse it for you (unless you specifically tell it to expect something else).

Comment: yep, `header()` on php can be safely omitted thanks for clarification

Comment: I realize I shouldn't need to parse json when I set dataType to json, but for whatever reason I simply have to. Not only do I have to parse it to JSON, but I also need the dataType : "json", I don't know why.